# Aborted during 18.04 config phase, how to resume?

Tags: upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and decided today to install the 18.04 version. I followed the instructions here: https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-linux-18-04/

After about 30-45 minutes I get to a phase of the installation where it is asking if my previously configured dotfiles should be overwritten with fresh ones from the upgraded packages. During one of them I select to view the diff, but then cannot find out how to exit the view. ESC, q, etc. don't work, so I try Ctrl-C, which results in a complete abort of the process. I'm afraid I now have a half-baked installation going. For example, System Settings only have about 7 entries, where the old version had about 20 or so. Also the Software & Updates part of the system settings looks completely wrong.

Running the command `sudo do-release-upgrade` results in a message that no new release is found. Is there any way to resume the configuration or re-run the installation?

Edit:

I have tried looking into other posts here and their solutions, but my problem is that dpkg is locked. For instance when I try `sudo apt-get install -f` I get:

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
>
> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Edit 2:

I came closer to what the problem really was. I restarted by mistake a found myself unable to log back in. I have a dual boot with Windows and use Grub to handle it. The standard Ubuntu option resulted in just a purple screen. Going to the Advanced options for Ubuntu, the first option resulted in the same error described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414655/not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0.

Not sure how the boot problem arose from the aborted OS upgrade, but here we are.

Comment: See updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I could log in using the second option under Advanced options for Ubuntu in the Grub menu. Once inside I ran the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and the configuration continued from where I had mistakenly aborted it. Everything works now!

I'll leave this up despite overlaps with other posted questions because of the slightly different situation.